# How handle AuthorizationException or AuthenticationException in Spring Kafka Listeners

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, error-handling, spring-kafka

I use @KafkaListener annotation for listen messages from topic.

And get

> 2024-01-18 17:08:34.966 [INFO ] [kafkaListener0-0-C-1] [o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator] [T:] - [Consumer clientId=consumer-kafkaAdapter_grpc_one2-1, groupId=kafkaAdapter_grpc_one2] FindCoordinator request hit fatal exception
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: kafka_grpc_one2
> 2024-01-18 17:08:34.967 [ERROR] [kafkaListener0-0-C-1] [o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer] [T:] - Authentication/Authorization Exception, retrying in 5000 ms
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: kafka_grpc_one2

I need to intercept the authorization error exception and log this information.
How handle GroupAuthorizationException, AuthorizationException or AuthenticationException exception?

KafkaListenerErrorHandler in KafkaListener annotation and CommonErrorHandler in ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory don't work with this case:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/annotation-error-handling.html

Comment: This closed issue may have some relevant information regarding this problem: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1826